# Naked domain not working when pointing godadddy domain to heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns, cname

I have a small laravel website that I built for a company on heroku. They had the domain registered with godaddy, so I altered the cname and it seems to work fine when I go to www.example.com.

However, when I go to http://example.com, the naked domain of example.com still ends up at the godaddy error page for a parked domain.

In heroku, I added a custom domain as www.example.com and entered the DNS target I was given.

Do I need to do something different for the naked domain?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add point DNS add on on heroku for your naked domain to work :
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pointdns